# A number field or currency amount field is required here in crystal Report

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports, datatables, type-conversion

Using VBNET2010 and A SQL Database and Crystal Report

I want To Calculate MIN,MAX,AVG of the fields of DataTable in column Fields

I tried Using

```
   Average({DataTable1.Column2})
```

I tried Using

MINIMUM ({DataTable1.Column2})

I tried Using

```
  Maximum({DataTable1.Column2})
```

Generate this Error message while in the processing of creating it:-
A number field or currency amount field is required here

Please help me, I need your help.
Thanks,

Or guide me how Get Min,Max Average in crystal report when i am using datatable as a source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey hey I got the Answer

for This You Have To create TWO formulas in Formula Editor

1.To convert the Datatable column to Number with Name avg

```
ToNumber({DataTable1.Column2})
```

And Second To Convert That number to AVG/MIN/MAX

```
Average ({@avg})
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to limit the report data set of the report to the maximum date per group?
in the select expert clcik on the Show formula box.
There is a Group Selection toggle. 
Switch it group selection
put your group selection criteria in there Maximum(DataTable1.Column2,group)

Comment: didn't get your point please brief what should i use at group